# Delete confirmation from Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, destroy, confirmation

I want to add a confirmation box before destroying an object in a controller. Basically, create the

```
data: {confirm: "You sure" }
```

but in a controller during `object.destroy` Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can only interact with the user in the view layer, so you need to make that confirmation before you go into the destroy method

Comment: I ended up doing an if else in the view layer so I could change the confirmation that way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can warn the user by simply add the **confirm** option to the link, and it will pop up a window to notify the user, same as using alert function in javascript.

`<%= link_to 'delete', delete_obj_path(obj), :method=>'delete', :confirm=>'You sure?'%>`